# Are there any datasets containing molecules with more than 38 heavy atoms?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, cheminformatics, databases, machine-learning

I have been testing a machine learning approach for molecular energy prediction. The current dataset that I have is QM9, which is consist of molecules with up to 9 heavy atoms.

I was wondering if anyone knows of available datasets that contain molecules with large numbers of heavy atoms. I will be testing ZINC, which has up to 38 atoms. Anyone knows of a larger dataset available?

Comment: In retrospect -- *after* giving providing *an* answer (molecules encoded as SMILES), while «user1271772» provided *an other* answer about molecules keeping geometries, does your question for a larger data set refer to a dataset containing molecules larger than 38 atoms, or a dataset with more molecules than ZINC?

Comment: Larger than 38 atoms. I was gonna say, but I appreciated your detail answer very much

Comment: Considering your additional input, I added a second part to my initial answer.  It is about an example which retains molecular geometries (similar to `.xyz` files) rather than a simplified representation as SMILES / InChi string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ISOL24 database (http://www.thch.uni-bonn.de/tc.old/downloads/GMTKN/GMTKN55/ISOL24.html) contains molecules with up to 81 atoms!

The other answer says that there's a database called "OE" with molecules that have up to 174 atoms, but it is "not yet publicly available".

Comment: Given the initial check in the work by Stuke *et al.* shown below, do you know about a similar survey about the entries in the ISOL24 database?

Comment: @Buttonwood: I do not understand your question.

Comment: The question was if there equally is a plot like figure 2 extracted from [doi/10.1063/1.5086105](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5086105) which a) depicts which elements are present or/and b) the the distribution of number of atoms per molecule for the ISOL24 database.  From its associated publiation in PCCP (Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.,
2017, 19, 32184, [DOI: 10.1039/c7cp04913g](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2017/CP/C7CP04913G#!divAbstract)) I retain it was setup to benchmark functionals and it were nice to compare it *this way* with the three sets below, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood: I agree that it would be nice to compare such a graphic representation. I do not know any such plot for ISOL24 though.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like you were exploring work *at least related* to the work by the [Lilienfeld group](https://chemspacelab.org) equally hosting a dedicated site [here](http://quantum-machine.org/) about data sets already used in their earlier and ongoing exploration of chemical space, programs used to work with the data, and publications.

To go considerably higher in molecule count than QM9, you could either go for

- GDB-11 about small organic molecules up to 11 atoms of C, N, O and F which «contains 26.4 million molecules (110.9 million stereoisomers), including three- and four-membered rings and triple bonds», described in *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2007**, 47, 342-353 ([doi.org/10.1021/ci600423u](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci600423u)), or
- GDB-13, about «small organic molecules up to 13 atoms of C, N, O, S and Cl following simple chemical stability and synthetic feasibility rules. With 977 468 314 structures, GDB-13 is the largest publicly available small organic molecule database to date».  This one was described in *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2009**, 131, 8732-8733 ([doi.org/10.1021/ja902302h](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja902302h))

Convienently, you can download both -- including sub-sets like «containing only carbon and nitrogen», or «chlorine and sulfur», or «fragrance like» in case you don't want to fetch 2GB of already compressed data -- from the [Reymond group](http://gdb.unibe.ch/downloads/). To quote: «All the molecules are stored in dearomatized, canonized SMILES format.»

The even larger GDB-17 («of up to 17 atoms of C, N, O, S, and halogens» with an universe of 166 billion entries, described in *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2012**, 52, 2864-2875, [[doi.org/10.1021/ci300415d](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci300415d), open access]) is accessible to the public on this site as a 50 million random subset only, partly because the gzipped archive is about 400GByte.  Among the publications citing this work is for example the Lilienfeld group again for machine learning (J. Chem. Phys. 143, 084111 (2015), [doi.org/10.1063/1.4928757](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4928757)).

---

Initially, I misinterpreted the question but think the answer may be more rounded by addition of the following complementary publication:  «Chemical diversity in molecular orbital energy predictions with kernel ridge regression» (*J. Chem. Phys.* **150**, 204121 (2019), [doi.org/10.1063/1.5086105](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5086105), preprint available [here](https://pure.mpg.de/pubman/faces/ViewItemOverviewPage.jsp?itemId=item_3070210)).  Aiming for a machine-learning analysis, the authors first compared QM9, 44k conformers of proteinogenic amino acids (AA), and a 64k set of organic molecules extracted from the CCDC potentially suitable for organic electronics (OE) for the content of atoms *per molecule* and found the following distribution:

[image]

To shed some light on them:

- QM9 represents 133,814 small organic molecules with up to 9 heavy atoms (C, N, O and F)
- AA is about «44,004 isolated and cation-coordinated conformers of 20 proteinogenic amino acids and their amino-methylated and acetylated (capped)
  dipeptides. The molecular structures are made of up to 39 atoms including H, C, N, O, S, Ca, Sr, Cd, Ba, Hg and Pb.»
- OE is about «64,710 large organic molecules with up to 174 atoms extracted from organic crystals in the Cambridge Structural Database (CSD). [...] The OE dataset is not yet publicly available. OE offers the largest chemical diversity among the sets in this work both in terms of size as well as number of different elements (Fig. 2). It contains the 16 different element types H, Li, B, C, N, O,  F, Si, P, S, Cl, As, Se, Br, Te and I.»

(The mentioned restriction sharing the original data relates to the user agreement with the CCDC.)

Further DFT-based property computations with these OE extracted molecular geometries lead to an ensemble of equilibrium molecular structures, and *these derived* geometries are accessible within a public [Jupyter notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook).  Shared with the public [here](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/1459255?show_id=1507656), the deposit comes with a guiding `tutorial.ipynb`, including an example how to retrieve these optimized geometries and display them with Jmol.

Comment: I don't think any of these have more than 81 atoms!

Comment: Ok I see the confusion. @Buttonwood perhaps you can answer this question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119804/what-is-the-dataset-with-the-largest-number-of-molecules

Comment: @user1271772 I think the updated answer offers both the avenue toward how to access the chemical space of many more (small) molecules (first half) as well as about molecules still considered as small yet more atoms per molecule.  Equally I perceive the diversity in the OE dataset regarding «types of molecules, which atoms are connected with each other» larger than for proteïns.  For a small-molecule chemist's view, the complexity of the later group emerges more from how theses amino acids are arranged in space ($\beta$-sheets, hairpins, helices, to mention a few complications).

Comment: Ok, so now you've shown two databases with fewer than 81 atoms, and one that has more than 81 atoms but is "not yet publicly available". The first half of this answer is completely unrelated to the question so I think it doesn't belong here at all.

Comment: The first part was based on a misunderstanding, clarified later.  The second   includes the derived coordinates e.g. in the df_62k.json for which both Jupyter notebook tutorial.ipynb (and equally tutorial.html) document `section #4 / working with molecular structures.  The optimized molecular structures are saved in xyz_pbe_relaxed. These entries contain molecular coordinates in the standard xyz-format.`  See on line `In [52]` as example `# We will write the molecules contained in df_subset2 to an xyz-trajectory (stacked xyz files)` and these xyz strings are processed further, too.

Comment: The first part was based on a misunderstanding that was clarified later. So why do you still have it in the answer to the question "what is the dataset containing the largest molecules?"

Comment: The first version of the question was titled by «Large molecule dataset» as about accessing *many molecules* which is orthogonal to the title now, «Dataset of Large Molecules».  The target moved, and so did the answer -- reproducible.  To me, the two parts don't contradict, they complement each other.  If QM9 contains up to nine non-H atoms per molecule, extraction of all DFT geometries from the 64k json yields a 128 MByte `.xyz` still including 471 entries with more than 100 atoms per molecule (up to the one with 174 atoms [75 of them non-H]).

Comment: I appreciate that you struggled to understand the original intention of the question, but to me it was very clear from the sentence: **"I was wondering if anyone knows of available datasets that contain molecules with large numbers of heavy atoms. I will be testing ZINC, which has up to 38 atoms."**  It is not at all true that the "target moved" it is that your understanding of the target moved (the asker never changed their mind about what they wanted). Anyway, I think your first effort was still valuable so I gave you a chance to let it be helpful as an answer to a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond other answers, I'd suggest the original [PubChemQC](http://pubchemqc.riken.jp) project, which offers ~3 million molecules from PubChem optimized using DFT (B3LYP/6-31G*). Molecules include a wide variety of elements as long as the molecular mass is less than 500 Da. (Roughly speaking that should still handle ~38 carbon atoms.)

["PubChemQC Project: A Large-Scale First-Principles Electronic Structure Database for Data-Driven Chemistry"](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.7b00083)
*J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2017** 57(6) pp. 1300-1308

You mention the number of heavy atoms, but keep in mind that QM9 only contains a small subset of elements and ZINC has many more.

Comment: It's somewhat of a pain to download the PubChemQC data files but they've demonstrated the use in ML methods both for ground-state energies and excitation energies using TD-DFT.