# What is the dataset with the largest number of molecules?

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

In computational chemistry we often apply techniques to all molecules of a "dataset". Recently it was asked which dataset contains the largest molecules, and a user accidentally  misinterpreted this as asking for the dataset with the largest *number* of molecules: [Datasets of Large Molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119797/large-molecule-dataset)

This question now gives that user an opportunity to give their answer here.

Comment: Despite the link to the related question, I think it won't hurt to add some more details what kind of dataset it's all about. The first thing that came to my mind was molecular structures from [CCDC database](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/), which I realized is not what is being asked for only after clicking the URL (or maybe I'm just not that smart:) ).

Comment: My answer would be the same for both questions: the PubChem database contains millions of structures ans is free.

Comment: @andselisk The original answer given, where I thought the question were accessing more and more molecules, got a second part; now pointing toward (retained) geometries of small molecules with more and more atoms.  From my perspective, this provides a more round perspective.  Equally, since you mention CCDC passing this summer the 1 millionth entry, I think [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/) deserves to be mentioned as well.  Which equally found its way into cheminformatics, e.g. as searchable supplementary file in [DataWarrior](http://www.openmolecules.org/datawarrior/datafiles.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one answer given to the initial question now equally addresses this perspective, too.  And I think it is worth to keep both perspectives, complementary in character, deposit in one spot in common.